# Does $ \sum _{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(n)\cdot(n^2+3)}{2^n} $ converge or does it diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Does this sum converge or diverge?

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(n)\cdot(n^2+3)}{2^n} $$

To solve this I would use $$ \sin(z) = \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} $$

and make it to $$\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\sin(n)\cdot\frac{(n^2+3)}{2^n} = \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{n^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} \cdot \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n^2+3)}{2^n} $$

and since $$\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n^2+3)}{2^n} \text{ and } \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{n^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} $$

converges $$ \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(n)\cdot(n^2+3)}{2^n} $$
would also converge.

Is my assumption true? I'm also a bit scared to use it since I've got the sin(z) equation from a source outside the stuff that my professor gave us

Comment: For such problems as these , you must use the Weierstrass M test, simple and handy.

Comment: I suppose you’re approach isn’t totally incorrect, but you would need to use two different indices for the summations and then justify swapping the order is summation to make an argument like this fully rigorous. Easier argument: just take absolute values and compare with $\sum \frac{n^2+3}{2^n}$. This will show that your sum converges absolutely, and hence converges.

Comment: It absolutely converges.

Comment: There are several technical mistakes (indexing and product of series) that make your development invalid.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! if i could i would've accepted all the answers below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly,

$$\left|\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\sin(n)(n^2+3)}{2^n}\right|<\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(n^2+3)}{2^n}.$$

Then by the ratio test, for $n\ge2$,

$$\frac12\frac{(n+1)^2+3}{n^2+3}\le\frac67$$ and the series converges.

Comment: I think what you need is $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left|\frac{\sin(n)(n^2+3)}{2^n}\right|<\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(n^2+3)}{2^n}$$ and not $$\left|\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\sin(n)(n^2+3)}{2^n}\right|<\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(n^2+3)}{2^n}$$

Comment: @GEdgar: not really. I wanted to show convergence of the initial series. I just skipped an intermediate step.

Answer (score 3):

By the same argument, since both series$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n}\quad\text{and}\quad\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n}$$are convergent (yes, they're equal), then the series$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n}\times\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n}\left(=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n\right)$$converges too. But it doesn't, right?

You can prove that your series converges using the comparison test or Dirichlet's test:

- the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin(n)$ has bounded partial sums;
- the sequence $\left(\frac{n^2+3}{2^n}\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is monotonic;
- $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2+3}{2^n}=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that for whatever $ p\geq 2 $, $ \lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}{\left|\frac{n^{p}\sin{n}\left(n^{2}+3\right)}{2^{n}}\right|}=0 $.

Thus $ \left|\frac{\sin{n}\left(n^{2}+3\right)}{2^{n}}\right|=\underset{\overset{n\to +\infty}{}}{\scriptsize\mathcal{O}}\left(\frac{1}{n^{p}}\right) $. Since $ \sum\limits_{n\geq 1}{\frac{1}{n^{p}}} $ converges for any $ p\geq 2 $, the series $ \sum\limits_{n\geq 1}{\left|\frac{\sin{n}\left(n^{2}+3\right)}{2^{n}}\right|} $ does also converge.

Our series does, hence, converge absolutely, which means it does converge.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't know how the $sin(x)$ as $x\to \infty$ behaves, you can use the fact that, if a series converges absolutely, then the original series converges. So you can see that

$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{sin(n)(n^2+3)}{2^n} \leqslant \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{n^2+3}{2^n}$

and I'll leave the rest to you... I just wanted to give some mental momentum.